# $(document).ready(function(){ in JQuery... worry about overwriting?

Tags: jquery, onload

In using this cool onload function from JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // my stuff }
```

do I need to worry about overwriting anything else that may have called it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@OneNerd** is right in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239993/109392) that it just adds to the ready queue. The `ready` method is declared in jQuery like this:

```
ready: function( fn ) {
    // Attach the listeners
    jQuery.bindReady();

    // Add the callback
    readyList.add( fn );

    return this;
},
```

Ref: http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

Answer (score 10):

In jQuery, that function adds to the ready queue I believe, so you can write multiple ready() functions without worrying about overwriting previous ones (they just stack).

Answer (score 2):

$(document).ready is an event, so as many subscribers as you want can wire up to it.